# Close as Duplicate still counts as linking?

Tags: support, comments, badges, hyperlinks

When voting to close because of Exact Duplicate, SE does a nice notion of linking the question in a comment. More of a theory then practice question, but would these links count towards the [Announcer](https://superuser.com/badges/64/announcer), [Booster](https://superuser.com/badges/65/booster) or [Publicist](https://superuser.com/badges/66/publicist) badge? As well, does the link being shared have to come from the same page, or can it be shared by other questions with similar topics where it would be useful to link?

Comment: My understanding is that they do not as they're internal links.

Comment: Internal links... So I have to use some sort of referral? As in, post NOT on an SE site and have NEW users click through?

Comment: @luke click in link you'll see a URL in form site/[q|a]/postid/userid - that userid is used to track referrals. And yes, that's right.

Comment: So no copy&pasting the address bar URL -- you need the *link* link and copy that instead. It's more Twitter-friendly anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links in comments and other posts do not count toward the count toward the share badges.

In order to add toward the count, you [have to link to the post from a site that is not on the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114607/do-shared-link-to-answers-also-count-for-announcer-booster-publicist-badges/114608#114608).

Comment: How about putting a link on SE chat? I assume that's `on the Stack Exchange network` and therefore doesn't count?

Comment: @Bob yeah, doesn't count.